# Mount Existing Hard Disk As /home And /data

Tags: linux, centos, partition, disk

I am running `CentOS 7.3` on `x86_64`. I have a two disk, first one is `256GB SSD` where `/root`, `/boot`, `swap` and `/home` is configured. 0Second one is a `4TB HDD` which is mounted as `/data` and currently has more than `1 TB` of data.

I want to expand `/home`, as it's not sufficient and will run out of space soon. To achieve this, I want to make use of the `4TB HDD` I have, such that I can use it both as `/home` and `/data`.

`/data` and not just `/home` because I already have some application and data configured with some absolute paths like `/data/xyz/pqr`.

Is it possible to achieve this without formatting anything and hopefully not loosing out on any data?

I am sharing below system information, if more details are required please let me know.

**df -h**

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   55G   27G   29G  50% /
devtmpfs              55G     0   55G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 55G     0   55G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 55G   18M   55G   1% /run
tmpfs                 55G     0   55G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1            1.9G  173M  1.7G  10% /boot
/dev/sdb1            3.6T  708G  2.8T  21% /data
/dev/mapper/cl-home  165G  3.0G  162G   2% /home
tmpfs                 11G   12K   11G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                 11G     0   11G   0% /run/user/1001
```

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
/dev/mapper/cl-root     /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=02663577-6456-477e-8489-3565659de456 /boot xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/cl-home     /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/cl-swap     swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1               /data                   ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You'll have to shrink the /data filesystem first. Umount it, check filesystem integrity:

```
e2fsck /dev/sdb1
```

Shrink with to 999G (or your desired size)

```
resize2fs /dev/sdb1 999G
```

And use gparted to resize the partition /dev/sdb1 to 1000G. Then you can fill the filesystem to the size of the /dev/sdb1 with:

```
resize2fs /dev/sdb1
```

Now you have the rest of the /dev/sdb available for your new /home. The best if you create there the LVM2 volume group (VG):

```
vgcreate lvm01 /dev/sdb2
```

And logical volume (LV) with sufficient size for your /home (500G is example).

```
lvcreate -n home.vol -L 500G lvm01
```

Create filesystem on the new LV

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/lvm01-home.vol
```

Then mount it under temporary mountpoint, logout from ordinary user and under root move content of the /home to the temporary mounpoint, change /etc/fstab entry of /home to the new LV and restart.

Comment: .@JaroslavKucera - To ensure I do as you explained, can you please share step by step process? I am bit lost after you said `gparted` but didn't saw the command above? I just want to ensure that I am not missing any steps and in process not crashing the system.

Comment: The gparted is GUI using parted backend. As you're not really power user, I'd suggest to use this GUI frontend. There is quite nice howto: https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

Comment: .@JaroslavKucera - Comfortable with Linux. I read `And use gparted`, so I thought I need to run `gparted` after I `resize2fs /dev/sdb1 999G`. Your solution should help.

Comment: I agree to the above except with the creation of a new volume group. Instead I would just add the new partition as a physical device to the existing volume group where /home is mounted and then increase that volume group with the space provided by the newly added PV.This way you don't have to move the data anymore.

Comment: It's all fine until moment, when one of disks dies. Then complete LV is gone...

Answer (score 0):

The "clean" solution would be

1. to shrink the `/data` partition (`resize2fs`)
2. to create a new partition in the free space, at best make it an LVM PV
3. create an LV `home`, format it
4. mount it to some temporary path
5. copy the `/home` data there
6. unmount `/home`
7. mount the new LV on `/home`

**simple alternative**

1. `mkdir /data/home`
2. `mv /home/* /data/home`
3. `rmdir /home`
4. `ln -s /data/home /`